# flask class and uri definition

Tags: python, flask, resources, uri, flask-restful

I'm starting to learn/build APIs using python and flask_restful. I understand that if i want to setup an uri i can do it like that for instance

```
api.add_resource(Item,'</item/<string:name>')
```

with a defined class Item for instance, and all the methode post get etc... inside

```
class Item(Resource)
```

But what should i do, if for example i want to use another, let's say for example this uri:
/item/string:name/get_status

For now, what i basically do, is create a dedicated class like

```
class Item_get_status(Resource)
```

and then set another ressource in my code:

```
api.add_resource(Item_get_status,'/item/<string:name>/get_status')
```

This seems a little bit awkward to me, but it works, i'm not sure that's the proper way to do it. I'm thinking of using inheritance principle in here, but i cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: i've looked at endpoint, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem: I think i made it the right right way for the code part, but i also think that it's not well designed, i should return the status in the get method, not in a dedicated path

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any way to do it, it seems that you NEED to create a different resource, the main "problem" is the design that i've implement i think: i should not use /get_status for the resource to get some kind of status, i should instead get it on the default post for the URI if the resource exist.